# Essentially self adjoint Dirac operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory, adjoint-operators

Let $T_0 :H^1_0(]0,1[) → L^2(]0,1[)$ be the Dirac operator defined by $T_0(f)=if’$ and 
$T:D → L^2(]0,1[)$ be an extension of $T_0$ where $D={{f \in{H^1(]0,1[)} ;f(0)=f(1)}}$

---

I have proved that $T_0$ is not self adjoint and $T$ is self adjoins, now I want to show that $T_0$ is essentialy self adjoint,so how can I prove that $T$ is the **unique** extension of $T_0$?

Comment: In $H^1_0$ we have f(0)=f(1)=0

Comment: Yes it is....,I have edited my first comment

Comment: Ah ok I misread $\{ f \in H^1, f(0) = f(1) = 0\}$. I don't see why $f(0) = f(1) =0$ or $f(1) = f(0) \ne 0$ changes self-adjoint ness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$T_0$ is not essentially selfadjoint because $T_0$ is closed and is not selfadjoint. There are many selfadjoint extensions of $T_0$. For example, if $0 \le \theta \lt \pi$, then $T_{\theta}$ is selfadjoint, where $T_{\theta}f=if'$ and where $\mathcal{D}(T_{\theta})$ consists of all elements $f$ of $H^1(0,1)$ for which $\cos\theta f(0)+\sin\theta f(1)=0$.

Comment: I didn’t get that $T_{\theta}$ is self adjoint